# Tinymce Not Checking words in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, tinymce, tinymce-4

Tinymce works fine in all browsers except IE8. It seems to miss random words as you type. Clicking the spell checker button just randomly underlines different wrongly spelt words.

[image: Tinymce words]

This looks fine server-side, which makes sense as it works in other browsers.

Comment: Spellcheck is a feature of the browser as far as I know, unless you're using spell checking systems which are not compatible with TinyMCE3.x which is the one you have in the screenshot

Comment: I see. Do you know any way around this? Or does tinymce just not work with ie8?

Comment: Tinymce does work with IE8, but for the spellcheck you'll need an external service if you don't want to relay on the browser one.

Comment: It does work, it's only the spell checker that is an issue with IE8. I have been playing with ieSpell, which is good, but you have to click the icon to check spelling. I would rather be able to click the word. Better keep looking!